# Find number of years between a VARCHAR and DATE in Netezza

Tags: netezza

What is the best way to calculate the number of years between a VARCHAR(200) and a date column in Netezza?

My column create_ts is a VARCHAR(200) and my mbr_dt_of_birth is a date but I am having issues when casting and using the datediff functions.

My mbr_dt_of_birth is in the following format 2003-10-06 00:00:00 while create_ts has the following 2017-01-25 16:15:28

I have tried the following snippets of code in my select statement but neither are working, can anyone tell me where i am going wrong please?

```
months_between(to_date(pahi.CREATE_TS),dmem.MBR_DT_OF_BIRTH)
```

and

```
DATEDIFF(year, CAST(pahi.CREATE_TS AS DATE),dmem.MBR_DT_OF_BRTH)
```

Comment: ‘Not working’ is very difficult to understand??? Do you receive an error or a wrong result?

Comment: Please provide a set of example input and output data. Several relevant sets please...,